# Is there any event to listen to a RTCRtpSender.replaceTrack

Tags: webrtc, rtp, webapi

I couldn't find any event to listen to an [RTCRtpSender.replaceTrack](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/RTCRtpSender/replaceTrack). Is there any option available to listen to that?

Answer (score 1):

There is not. replaceTrack is an operation that is initiated by the user (so if you are calling it why do you need an event to tell you).
On the receiver side replaceTrack is not observable, that is intentional.